# SMT PCBA production

Tags: surface-mount, pcb-assembly, packages

I am interested in setting up an SMT factory for producing PCBA. I have researched and know the whole assembly process such as solder paste application, reflow oven, etc. Regarding the packaging of finished products, I saw videos online and also read articles where it is done manually. Are there any ways to do the whole packaging of finished products in an automated system? If not, could this process be done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

PCBA's come in different sizes and shapes.

With that said, it's not that easy automatizing the packaging of finished products in antistatic envelopes and then in carton boxes ready for shipping.

I visited small size PCBA companies over here in Italy and Switzerland and I've never seen that process to be automatic.

I figure, that middle to big companies purchase custom machines for doing that kind of job when production volume begin to grow.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Customers like me prefer suppliers that have X-ray inspection machines to see in details how many voids are in solder joints. The soldering process can be described in terms of voids. Voids make solder joints fragile especially over time.